# Sugar CRM Module install issue

Tags: linux, module, permissions, crm, sugarcrm

I uploaded the Module in Sugar CRM using Module Loader and it is showing in the list but while I try to install it shows me the following error.

**Display Log**

> Failed to copy
>   cache/upgrades/temp/BqJ0Hh/SugarModules/modules/ls_l2schat to
>   modules/ls_l2schat

I have given permissions necessary permission to all folders but still getting the same error.

and the directory "cache/upgrades/temp/" is empty. Please let me know how to fix this issue OR debug step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means that your manifest.php is incorrect and it doesn't correspond to what is actually in the zip. Check to see if /SugarModules/modules/ls_l2schat exists in your module's zip file. If it is, check again and make sure that the spelling and casing is EXACTLY right.

Comment: Thanks but Module is installed on my local windows system in sugar CRM. Issue is on Linux system. Already given the permission but still getting error.

Comment: Exactly, so check the casing of the path then.

Comment: if it works on Windows but not Linux then the issue is either case sensitivity or file permissions.